# Angular 8 returns invalid Date

Tags: angular, date

My goal is to get "this.mypensionsort.dtFin", to add 1 day to this date, and to reaffect this date with a formated Date, but the object "this.mypensionsortbis.dtDebut" returns an invalid date an I don't understrand why ... Morevover, what id the local code for France ??

```
  const newDate = new Date(this.mypensionsort.dtFin);
  const dateDayPlusOne = new Date(newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + 1));
  const formatedDate = new Date(formatDate(dateDayPlusOne, 'dd/MM/yyyy', 'en-US'));
  this.mypensionsortbis.dtDebut = formatedDate;
```

---

I have forgotten mypensionsort is defined like this :

```
  mypensionsort: PensionInvalidite;
```

And PensionInvalidite like this :

```
 export class PensionInvalidite {

  id: number;
  dtDebut: Date;
  dtFin: Date;
  montant: number;
  nivInvalidite: NivInvalidite;
  organisme: OrganismeFinanceur;
  indicateur: Indicateur;
  orderDisplay: number;


  constructor() {}

}
```

Comment: Since we do not know how `this.mypensionsort` is defined or assigned initially, we cannot know either.

Comment: Local code for France is **FR**

Comment: From what code you show, `dtFin` will be undefined, which will cause  `new Date` to return 'Invalid date'. Make sure all variables are initialized to valid values